# i cant Load value into array

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
UserArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &db) == SQLITE_OK)
{

    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"select UserName,FullName,Email from User" ];
    const char *sqlStatement =[querySQL UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db ,sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW ) 
        {
            NSString *aUserName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
            NSString *aFullName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
            NSString *aEmail = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];


            // Create a new animal object with the data from the database
            User *obj_user = [[User alloc] initWithUserName:aUserName FullName:aFullName Email:aEmail];

            // Add the animal object to the animals Array
            [UserArray addObject:obj_user];

            [User release];
        }
    }

    // Release the compiled statement from memory
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}

sqlite3_close(db);
```

}

Hey All,

```
I am trying to put value into array of object but it throw's error Like Below...
anyone guide me why i got this type of error.
```

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICachedDeviceRGBColor UserArray]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a396f0'

Comment: Are you sure that exception is raised in this part of code? I think that it's somewhere else. Please, post the stack trace.

Comment: Instance variables should begin with lowercase. eg userArray. Save uppercase for Classes, eg. User. When you call [User release] it is not clear if you are messaging a class or an instance. If it is a class then you have a bug. Did you mean [obj_user release]? Similarly use lowercase for method names initWithUserName:fullName:email:

Comment: I am sure performing a nil check before operation like these can save you from lot many problems [UserArray addObject:obj_user]; also before calling User *obj_user = [[User alloc] initWithUserName:aUserName FullName:aFullName Email:aEmail];